# Jhipster registry gives me an Exit: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with result = null

Tags: jhipster-registry

I have a problem with Jhipster registry:

- git clone https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry
- cd jhipster-registry
- mvnw

And I get this back (while my browser is empty...)

```
2019-03-18 16:22:41.069  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-03-18 16:22:41.455  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       : Started JHipsterRegistryApp in 25.837 seconds (JVM running for 26.822)
2019-03-18 16:22:41.465  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Application 'jhipster-registry' is running! Access URLs:
        Local:          http://localhost:8761
        External:       http://192.168.56.1:8761
        Profile(s):     [composite, dev, swagger]
----------------------------------------------------------
2019-03-18 16:22:41.465  INFO 24384 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp       :
----------------------------------------------------------
        Config Server:  Connected to the JHipster Registry config server!
----------------------------------------------------------
2019-03-18 16:22:45.980 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
2019-03-18 16:22:46.756 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Exit: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
2019-03-18 16:22:51.762 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
2019-03-18 16:22:51.762 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Exit: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
2019-03-18 16:22:56.765 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
2019-03-18 16:22:56.765 DEBUG 24384 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Exit: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
```

When I make a yarn to install dependencies

```
D:\BasuraTemporal\Jhipster\microservicetest1\jhipster-registry>yarn
yarn install v1.10.1
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.12.9".
warning " > @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.8" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.7".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
$ node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js
Found PhantomJS at D:\BasuraTemporal\Jhipster\microservicetest1\jhipster-registry\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ...verifying
PhantomJS is previously installed at D:\BasuraTemporal\Jhipster\microservicetest1\jhipster-registry\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
Done in 286.35s.
```

The result is the same:

```
2019-03-18 17:01:50.152 DEBUG 17880 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Enter: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with argument[s] = []
2019-03-18 17:01:50.152 DEBUG 17880 --- [pool-3-thread-1] i.g.j.r.aop.logging.LoggingAspect        : Exit: io.github.jhipster.registry.service.ZuulUpdaterService.updateZuulRoutes() with result = null
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open a command prompt and do a:

> yarn start

And then in another command prompt you can do you mvnw.

Check Build from start: https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/